# DirectApiAuthorizationRequired with Microsoft Flow calling Microsoft Flow

Tags: http, power-automate

I'm attempting to incorporate subroutines in Microsoft Flow, which seems to be done by creating a flow called via HTTP by another Flow per [posts online](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/build-nested-flows/). Creating a simple flow that I can call from Postman works great. The problem occurs when I call it from my main flow.

It wanted an API version, so I set the query api-version to 2016-10-01

Now, when it runs, it gives the error

```
    "code": "DirectApiAuthorizationRequired",
    "message": "The request must be authenticated only by Shared Access scheme."
```

Again, the called flow works fine from Postman. It's when called from Flow that it gives the error. All the steps I see online are for Logic App or other tools. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I discovered that when I was recopying the URL, that I had lost the authentication information has it had been moved to Queries in my REST client, so the code was not actually authenticating. So, if anyone else has this issue, copy the URL from the original source!

Answer (score 1):

You might also encounter this issue with curl, even if you copied the URL from the flow's trigger.

If this is the case, remember to put the URL between double quotes, to ensure the request parameters are correctly sent.